# Navbar shrinking with fixed position

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind-css in my svelte app. Why does the following navbar shrink when I set the position to fixed?

```html
<nav class="container left-0 top-0 w-full bg-white">
        <div class="flex">
        <!-- navbar elements -->
        </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Without fixed position]

With

```html
    <nav class="container fixed left-0 top-0 w-full bg-white">
```

[image]

Comment: try right-0 along with left-0

Comment: That centers the navbar, leaving space on both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely the use of the `container` class, not the `fixed` class.

In TailwindCSS, `container` is used for constraining an elements width to the width of the current breakpoint.

[image]

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container

So let's say your screen is currently 1200px wide. The container will always be 1024px wide—even if you set `w-full`. Because the max width in the large breakpoint is 1024px.

When you update the size to `max-w-full`, you're essentially removing this constraint on the size, letting the `nav` span the full width of the screen. Adding the `max-w-full` class cancels out the `container` class. So you can actually get the same result if you remove both the `container` and `max-w-full` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by modifying class w-full to max-w-full, although I'm not sure exactly why it made so much of a difference